# Extjs 5.1: overflowHandler: 'Menu' not working correctly for toolbar

Tags: javascript, menu, toolbar, extjs5

I'am using the property `overflowHandler: 'Menu'` to configure my toolbar

but when I clicked in the button to show the rest of buttons it shows me an empty List

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        layout: {
         overflowHandler: 'Menu'
         },
        items: [
            {
                iconCls: 'add',
                text: 'Add external document',
                handler: 'onAddClick'
                //menu: Ext.create('bdociTabletProto.view.folder.list.DocumentsList')
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'edit'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'edit'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'edit'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'edit'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            }, ,
            {
                iconCls: 'edit'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'delete'
            },
            '->',
            '-',
            {
                iconCls: 'pdf',
                toggleGroup: 'documentPermission'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'html',
                toggleGroup: 'documentPermission'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `overflowText` property in every Item like that:

```
items: [
            {
                iconCls: 'delete',
                overflowText: 'delete'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'edit',
                overflowText: 'edit'
            }
]
```

Thanks a lot  -_-